# embed video object in html using django

Tags: html, django

I am having trouble to embed a video content file from my cloud to my webpage.

I am developing using Django framework

I am using pyrax to get the file from Rackspace cloud.

Here is my code:

```
def getfile(request):
 file =  object.fetch() // this return the file content of video file that's stored in cloud
 return render(request,'index.html',{'file':file})
```

my HTML

```
{% if file%} <video height='320' width='320' controls> <source src='file:'{{file}} type='video/mp4'> </video> {% endif %}
```

with the above code i am getting an error

> No video with supported format and MIME type found

Can anyone help me with this,
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried running this on different browser ? also what is object.fetch() actually returning ? please do a print(file) and see if it is returning the url for that video.

Comment: it return the content of the file , it doesn't give us a url. They content will be of stream of bytes value like '\xc6\x00\x00\x01\xa9\x00\x00\x01\xc2\x00'

Comment: `<source src={{ path_to_url }} type='video/mp4'>` src tag take the path to video. here browser is having trouble to load the video. `object.fetch()` is returning the object. you first need to parse the url from it and then pass.

Comment: do you know any way inorder to dispay the video based on stream of byte instead of URL

Comment: please update your question with more detail. like what cloud service you are using and what are you fetching, i mean what url or api. and your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Two view function in which one view to render the HTML and another view return a response of the video.

```
def mainView(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def returnVideo(request):
    pyrax.set_setting('identity_type', 'rackspace')
    pyrax.set_credentials(USERNAME, API_KEY)
    cp = pyrax.cloudfiles
    container = cp.get_container('test')
    object = container.get_object('test.mp4')
    file = object.fetch()
    response = HttpResponse(file,content_type='video/mp4')
    response['Content-Disposition'] ='filename=myfile.mp4;inline'
    response['Content-Length'] = object.total_bytes
    return response
```

To make them viewavle in HTML we can provide the source URL to the returnVideo view

```
<video controls='true' height="320" width="320">
        <source src="{% url 'returnVideo' %}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This method works fine without any issue.